# how to stretch background image to full page and for different pages with different heights?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have this image   "ignore the red line on top of the image"
[image]

And i want this image to be the background of my html page it starts with white and ends with blue, all what I want is: using css to stretch this image in the background based on the page height, for example in some pages the page height become 2000px with scroll in the browser, and some pages height 1000px, i need all pages to use the same background image and just stretch it using css.

I want this to run on all browsers  including IE 7,8,9

what I tried to do is:

```
div.fullscreen
{
    display: block; /*set the div in the top-left corner of the screen*/
    /*set the div in the top-left corner of the screen*/
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../images/landingpage_bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

but it didn't stretch well.

Answer (score 0):

```
html { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

the only 1 way, is to crop your pic, put it to background bottom with repeat-x and use border-top on body\html, or whatever you'll use for your pic

Comment: sorry, didnt see that red border isnt on top on image. Well the only one way its to cut red border from image. And then put it as background: background:url("image") bottom left repeat-x. And create div with border bottom, for your red border